# Real numbers and positive real numbers have same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

How to prove that real numbers and positive real numbers have same cardinality?  I know you have to construct a bijective function mapping one to the other.  But I have trouble finding this particular function.  Thanks!

Comment: $\exp(x)$ works?

Answer (score 4):

This question has been answered in a comment:

> $\exp(x)$ works? –  janmarqz Jan 28 at 2:26